# PhpStorm shows red circle

Tags: phpstorm

Sometimes, when hovering over an element in PhpStorm I'm seeing a red circle above it. Could one of you explain why this happens and how to solve it?

[image: red circle when hovering above terminal close icon]

[image: red circle when hovering above terminal close icon]

Comment: Looks like it unable to load (or process,e.g. make lighter/darker) that icon for whatever reason?.. Possibly JDK issue. If it bothers/distracts you -- better report it as a bug to their Issue Tracker -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Could also be a corrupted installation. Did you try to reinstall PhpStorm? Note that installation always should be performed into a completely empty directory.

Comment: Can you show a bigger picture so we get it in full context please.

Comment: Also please try to disable all external plugins and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem! Thanks for your kind responses.

I uninstalled PhpStorm, deleted all the directories mentioned [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-phpstorm-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) and installed it again.